# Search style EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext

I would like to use the "search" style EditText, with the thin line underneath and a microphone icon on the right (although I would replace that icon with a different function), used in apps like Youtube and Google maps.

Is this a native element of this in any versions of Android? I can't seem to find a reference to it anywhere, although I did find this:

[Android EditText like Google Search EditText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8562241/android-edittext-like-google-search-edittext)

Which basically says to create it yourself, which I've done, however if there's a more "native" search EditText I'm unaware of, I'd rather use that...

Thanks for your help.

Comment: AFAIK, there is not a built-in class in the Android SDK that does this.

Comment: You can see [my answer **here**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11093987/1050058). It's easy to change the icon to the right. Try yourself first. I'll add another snippet later with icon in the right

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have this Search-EditText inside of an app, here you will find all information needed:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/index.html

Google provides configuration examples for both Android 2.X without ActionBar and later Androids with ActionBar. Under "Creating a Search Interface" you will find the section "Adding Voice Search" which brings in the microphone icon, though I don't know how to override its functionality.